# Net type, variable type, data type and data objects

Tags: hdl, system-verilog

I am really confused by the conception of net type, variable type, data type and data objects in SystemVerilog. I am using the simulator inside Xilinx Vivado 2018.02 for all the following codes.

`logic` in SystemVerilog can partially substitute the role of `wire` in Verilog. Say I have the following code within a module

```
logic q_bar;
logic q;
assign q_bar = ~q;
always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if(!rst)
        q <= 1'b0;
    else
        q <= q_bar;
end
```

Does the compiler infer a net type for `q_bar` since we `assign`ed it? `q` is of variable type since its assignment is in a procedural block.
Another example:

```
typedef logic [7:0] mem_t[3:0][3:0];
typedef wire [7:0] byte_wire_t;
```

The first line is legal, but the simulator complains about the second one: "SystemVerilog keyword wire used in incorrect text". But the grammar of `typedef` is

```
typedef data_type type_identifier { variable_dimension } ;
| typedef [ enum | struct | union | class | interface class ] type_identifier ;
...
```

Isn't `wire` a data type? Is net type a data type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `wire` is not a **data type**; it is a **net type**. SystemVerilog has some confusing implicit declaration defaults to be backward compatible with Verilog.

When you write the following in Verilog:

```
wire w;
```

it's the same as this following in SystemVerilog:

```
wire logic w;
```

This means `w` is a net with a 4-state data type (0,1,x or z). And the `wire` *kind* of net  means it can have multiple drivers with different strengths. When there are conflicting states with the same strength, the net resolves to the X state. Other kinds of *net types* use AND or OR to resolve conflicts. Net types cannot have procedural assignments.

When you write the following declaration in Verilog:

```
logic v;
```

it's the same as this following declaration in SystemVerilog:

```
var logic v;
```

This means `v` is a variable with a 4-state data type (0,1,x or z). And being a variable means it is allowed to have only one continuous assignment, or any number of procedural assignments. It cannot have both kinds of assignments.

Whether a variable gets synthesized into a Register/flop or physical metal wire depends on its usage.

You may also want to read http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg

BTW, there are slight differences in the defaults for module port declarations. For example `(input logic w)` defaults to a `wire` **net type**,  not a variable.

Comment: "`w` is a net with a 4-state data type...". Could I understand it this way: data types could be attached to a net type or a variable type. For the net type, only a 4-state data type is allowed. For the variable type, both the 4-state and 2-state (`logic` and `bit`) are allowed.

Comment: Yes. The built-in net types can only have 4-state data types, including `struct, enum`. For non-synthesizable code, variables can be any data type, i.e. `real`.